# How to reference another SE post

Tags: support, android-app

On the Android SE app, how do I (1) cut a link to an SE post and (2) include it in my own SE post our comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the "share" tool and select "Copy to clipboard"
2. Edit a post and long-press to "paste" the URL into the post